# How to navigate when using netrw-R (rename)

Tags: cursor-movement, netrw

Often I rename files using `netrw-R`. It opens a rename confirmation on the commandline(?). E.g.

```
Moving /home/ber/Documenten/xxx/xxx/test/services/member_balance_calculator_test.rb to : /home/ber/Documenten/xxx/xxx/test/services/member_balance_calculator_test.rb
```

Let's say, I want to change the name to `calculate_member_balance_test.rb`. All I can get to work, is

- Hit the <kbd>left</kbd> 7 times
- Hit <kbd>backspace</kbd> 9 times
- Hit <kbd>left</kbd> another 13 times
- Type `calculate`

I'm sure there is a way to navigate and operate this "dialog" more efficient but don't see where or how. Nor do I know where to look in the `:help` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part of the documentation is `:help cmdline-editing` but, as you can see, the possibilities are pretty limited.

Your best option is to open the "command-line window" with `<C-f>`, which lets you edit the current command-line with the full power of Vim.

See `:help cmdline-window`.